# Is my double being altered?

Tags: java, format, double

So I have

```
double a= 199812280115
```

When I

`System.out.println(a);`

I get

```
1.9981228E13
```

This representation of `double a` does not imply that the value stored has been altered right?

Answer (score 5):

The double value printed in the console has been formated, according to the default toString() vaue, but the value remains the same. If you wish to print the value "as is", you should use a `NumberFormat` to format and print.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to check if your value is altered is by doing something like this:

```
double a= 199812280115;
double b= 199812280000;
double c = a - b;
System.out.println(c);
```

You'll see yourself if your double has lost precision.

Comment: Of course `b` could have lost precision as well... But yes this is a helpful approach.

Answer (score 1):

**YES,** the output you see does show that the value has been altered.

Note that you see only 8 digits after the decimal point. The `double` data type has enough precision for 15-16 digits after the decimal point. The default formatting in Java outputs the least amount digits that are required to distinguish the number from its neighbors so you should see all of the digits.

Besides, the exponent is wrong. The expected output is `1.99812280115E11`.

Comment: How is the value being altered? `199812280115` and `1.99812280115E11` look equivalent to me, with no loss of precision

Comment: @kuporific, the OP reports getting 1.9981228E13.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
System.out.format("%12f", a);
```

To see the number in its full glory.

Comment: Since `a` is a double, this does not work with a format string of `"%12d"`, it should probably be `"%12f"`.